# Codeigniter controller model call fail

Tags: php, codeigniter, sql-update

I am new to CI and I want to update some data in mysql . So here is my controller

```
class Ci_update extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function index()
    {
        $data = array
        (
          'title' => 'Data Structure using C',  
          'text' => 'Data Structure Using C, for, IIIrd Sem VTU CSE students'
        );
        $id = 4 ;

        $this->load->model('ci_update_model');
        $this->ci_update_model($data,$id);
    }
}
```

and my model is :

```
class Ci_update_model extends CI_Model
{
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function updateData($data,$id)
    {
        $this->db->where('id',$id);
        $this->db->update('data',$data);
    }
}
```

But when I tried to run the program , it says `Call to undefined method Ci_update::ci_update_model() in C:\wamp\www\ci\application\controllers\ci_update.php on line 19`
What wrom am I doing?

Comment: When you have load the model you have to call function inside it $this->ci_update_model->function($var)... not just $this->ci_update_model($var) ...in your case you are searching for Function ci_update_model inside the controler class..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use as below

```
$this->load->model('ci_update_model');
$this->ci_update_model->updateData($data,$id);
```

Answer (score 0):

DO this changes in your Controller code,Rest is same:

```
 $this->load->model('ci_update_model');
 $this->ci_update_model->updateData($data,$id);
```

Answer (score -3):

in your controller's constructer add this line

```
$this->load->model('Ci_update_model');
```

and the error will get resolved

Comment: if you load the model in your constructor then you do not need to load the model in the remaining functions of the controller's file. So I would recommend you to load the model in the constructor itself to avoid using `$this->load->model('Ci_update_model');` in each and every function which you are having.

Comment: The problem is not at loading the model, its at calling the function inside it.. And if he need it just at one controller function why to load it for all (in the constructor)?

Comment: In CI we use a couple of other functions along with index function.

Comment: the asked question has only a one error which is that the function of model calling is wrong.

Comment: @SahilJariwala I code in CI and I load models only where I need them..
You don't need to load models where you don't use them.. Its just takes more time to proccess.